# Firefox QuickFind Not Working After Content Loaded?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, firefox

I have built a small web based application to help us with a few jobs at work running on a local web server, my colleagues have for years used the QuickFind feature in Firefox (pressing the forward slash key to search the page) when using my application.

I'm in the process of re-building this and have run into a problem. My application now uses alot of jQuery including a hashchange function to load the page content and modal windows. I found that if you click anywhere inside the document then refresh the page the QuickFind hot key still works however if you refresh again (pressing F5 or clicking) the hot key no longer works. This same problem occurs when I load a modal window, once the modal has loaded the hot key no longer works.

Has anyone got any idea what may be causing this and how to fix it? Currently the only other option I can see is to write my own search function but it's really not a route I'd like to take if it can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution to this. The problem turned out to be that I was using the .load() function on a 5 second timer and this was causing the document to lose focus. Calling the following code after the .load() eliminates the problem.

```
window.focus();

if (document.activeElement) {
    document.activeElement.blur();
}
```